# How to write ッ on keyboard

Tags: discussion

Some small Katakana use "x" followed by "i", "u", "e", etc. which makes characters such as "ィ", "ゥ", "ェ".

Typing "xx" will make "ッx", and if you follow that up with "i", "u", "e", etc., you get "ッィ", "ッゥ", "ッェ".

But if you want to type something like "メッセージを入力", how can you type "ッ" without deleting the leftover "x"?

I should mention that this is on a Mac, but I see that this holds true on Android's Google Japanese keyboard as well.

Comment: Anything wrong with just typing messe-ji?

Comment: Ahh, I see now. You effectively need to pay attention to the kana that follows "ッ", and use the first letter of the following kana twice. In this case, "sse" makes "ッセ". Thank you. 

Everywhere else kept alluding to utilizing "x" when writing out the desired word.

Comment: <not answering the question, but>, while I didn't know x could be used that way, also l (small L) works the same way; I think it is easier to remember (l=little) Anyway, while I would also use messe-ji　but now that you mention, also mextsuse-ji works.

Answer (score 3):

The small kana ッ or っ appear for any double consonant, so `ss` converts to `っs` with the second `s` waiting for a vowel, so メッセージ can be input typing `messe-ji`.

You can also use `x`, as in `xtu` or `xtsu` (for example for typing a final small っ with nothing coming after it), but it's usually faster to type `tt` → `っt`, say, and delete the final `t`.